# Swift Completion Handler for mapView.setRegion Animation?

Tags: swift, animation, completionhandler

I'm trying to figure out how to tell when the animation is finished for the following:

`self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(mapRect), animated: true)`

It doesn't look like `setRegion` supports a completion handler like other commands.

I know how to create a generic completion handler using something like this:
[How could I create a function with a completion handler in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401439/how-could-i-create-a-function-with-a-completion-handler-in-swift)

But I don't know what variable to check to verify the animation has completed.

Answer (score 5):

You can implement the `MKMapViewDelegate` [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate) for this purpose. From the docs:

> Because many map operations require the MKMapView class to load data
>   asynchronously, the map view calls these methods to notify your
>   application when specific operations complete.

This method should do what you want:

```
optional func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool)
```

> Tells the delegate that the region displayed by the map view just
>   changed.