# What is the right way to pass the value get from closure to other class?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I want to get value for variable `guestname` from closure and `guestname` is defined as global virable then pass this value to other class that use it. But the problem is that when i print out the `guestname` outside the closure it's empty but inside i see the actual value. So when i passed `guestname` to other class it pass nil caused problem. What is correct way to assign the value to `guestname` and get this value out of closure? Thanks

```
queryUserID?.getFirstObjectInBackground(block: { (object, error) in
                if error == nil {
                guestname = object!.value(forKey: "username") as! String

                }
            })
```

Comment: I tried to add completion hander but still the empty value first then later assign the value..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your closure performs an async task, so obviously you will not get the value of your "guestname" variable outside. This is where completion blocks come into play. You can write a completion block for your closure and return the fetched result.

Look at this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30401560/2513947) which explains your scenario and teaches you how to write a completion block for your closure. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must pass data from closure itself like all completion blocks do

```
queryUserID?.getFirstObjectInBackground() { [weak CLASS] (object, error) in
    if let unwrappedObject = object as? String,
        error == nil {
            guestname = unwrappedObject.value(forKey: "username")
            CLASS?.passData(guestname)
    }
}
```