# NSAttributed String missing return value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make this function inside a VC into a function within an extension (because I need to access it in multiple VC's so I'm trying to return the attributedStringWithRtf so i can use it elsewhere.

```
func populateTextViewWithCurrentScene() {

    let fileURL = getFileURL()

    do {
        let attributedStringWithRtf:NSAttributedString = try NSAttributedString(
            url: fileURL,
            options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf],
            documentAttributes: nil
        )
        self.textViewOutlet.attributedText = attributedStringWithRtf
    }
    catch {
        print("failed to populate text view with current scene with error: \(error)")

    }

}
```

So far, I've tried this, following the guide here [How could I create a function with a completion handler in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401439/how-could-i-create-a-function-with-a-completion-handler-in-swift) and I've also tried a version declaring a var before the function. The error I'm getting on the below is Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSAttributedString'.

I know there are quite a few questions about this sort of thing but a lot are for old versions of Swift

```
func populateTextViewWithCurrentScene(rtfString: NSAttributedString) -> Void {

    let fileURL = getFileURL()
    do {
        let rtfString:NSAttributedString = try NSAttributedString(
            url: fileURL,
            options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf],
            documentAttributes: nil
        )
    }
    catch {
        print("failed to populate text view with current scene with error: \(error)")
    }
    rtfString()
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the first function? The question has nothing to do with completion handlers.

Comment: You should read the [Function Parameters and Return Values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID160) section of the Swift book. Note that you have no need for a completion handler. Just a normal return value.

Comment: @vadian I'm wanting to use the output (the attributed string) to then set the .text property of a textView elsewhere in the code. So I need to return (I think) the attributed string .i.e. remove this line....         self.textViewOutlet.attributedText = attributedStringWithRtf so I can use the attributed string on multiple text views in multiple places in the code without writing it all out again

Comment: @rmaddy I tried doing that but I can't access attributedStringWithRtf for the return?

Comment: Show that attempt in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and created an `extension` of `UIViewController` that should provide what you are looking for. Comments are included for each line to explain the decisions that I made.

Feel free to comment if some part is unclear, or does not work as expected.

```
import UIKit

// You mentioned wanting to extend your viewcontroller
// so I extend UIViewController to support that
extension UIViewController {
    // Returns an optional NSAttributedString, based upon successfully loading the file contents
    func loadString() -> NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            // Everything is cleaned up into a single return command,
            // including the getFileURL, which can be used as a parameter instead
            // of creating a variable for it
            return try NSAttributedString(url: getFileURL(),
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            // If this fails, use your existing print command
            print("failed to populate text view with current scene with error: \(error)")
            // and then return nil to indicate that nothing was loaded
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

This is building off of the comments below from you and rmaddy.

As referenced in my original comment, the solution was not consolidating the try & return, that was simply to streamline the code.

You can look at the function this way:

> "I want to try and open a file that is located at `getFileURL()`, and
>   would like to use some options I specify with my `options:` parameter.
>   Since this action can fail, Xcode makes me use `try`.
>   Assuming that this file is successfully opened, then return the
>   contents back to the caller in the form of an `NSAttributedString`.
>   However, if this fails, print out a message telling me why it failed
>   and then return a `nil` to indicate that no data is returned."

Comment: I suggest renaming the method.

Comment: thanks for this one - the key (which I didn't know) was that you can pre-pend try with return (probably a silly omission but still relatively new to coding so I'm sure this will help others in the same situation)

Comment: @nc14 The "key" has nothing to do with prepending `try` with `return`. You can easily write this as `let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(....)` followed by `return attrStr`.