# Adding a completion handler to a framework's delegate function for response handling (Epson Printer)

Tags: swift, printing, epos

So I have logic handling a queue of print jobs (Which is how all of our other printer integrations are handled) that calls specific functions for each printer (in this case, the **sendCommand** function) that does the print job, then reports back success / fail so we can properly handle retrying or removing the print job document.

```
func sendCommand(_ commands: Data, portName: String, portSettings: String, timeoutMilis: uint_least32_t) -> Bool {
    doPrinterSetup()
    let succPrint = cutAndCompletePrintJob(commands)
    if (connectedPrinter != nil) {
        disconnectPrinter()
    }
    while (!hasCompleted) { //Awful solution?
        sleep(1)
    }
    return printSuccess
}
```

Inside the printer's specific logic, I establish a connection, build the print data, ect... then send it. The response here I get is that the command has sent successfully.

```
func printData(_ data: Data) -> Bool {
    if connectedPrinter == nil {
        return false
    }
    connectedPrinter!.addCommand(data) //Add print information
    connectedPrinter!.addCut(EPOS2_CUT_FEED.rawValue) //Add cut
    connectedPrinter!.beginTransaction()
    connectedPrinter!.sendData(Int(EPOS2_PARAM_DEFAULT))
    return true
}
```

The EPOS framework has a separate delegate function, **onPtrReceive** that is called once the print job has actually finished printing, seen below, which actually reports the success or failure of printing the job:

```
//EPOS Delegate func
func onPtrReceive(_ printerObj: Epos2Printer!, code: Int32, status: Epos2PrinterStatusInfo!, printJobId: String!) { 
    hasCompleted = true
    
    print("Status in onPtrReceive \(makeErrorMessage(status))")
    
    dispPrinterWarnings(status)
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async(execute: {
        self.connectedPrinter!.endTransaction()
        self.connectedPrinter!.disconnect()
        self.connectedPrinter!.clearCommandBuffer()
        self.connectedPrinter!.setReceiveEventDelegate(nil)
        })
}
```

Now, the problem is that I have to wait for the response to **sendCommand** before responding to my parent class handling the print jobs, but I am at a loss on how to actually pass a completion handler to the framework delegate function and do it the proper way. Currently I have the global variable **hasCompleted** which I have a while loop stopping it from responding until **onPtrReceive** sets it to true, however I am under the impression this is an awful solution. Any suggestions on how to handle this the proper way or is this an acceptable strategy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could I create a function with a completion handler in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401439/how-could-i-create-a-function-with-a-completion-handler-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use closure for this problem.

add a closure parameter to the `sendCommand` method and remove the Bool return value, hold this parameter as you class property.

```swift
// Bool stand for the status of this printing job, true means success.
var completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?

func sendCommand(_ commands: Data, portName: String, portSettings: String, timeoutMilis: uint_least32_t, completion: @escaping (Bool -> Void)?) {
    self.completion = completion
    // ....
}
```

call this closure in the delegate method.

```swift
func onPtrReceive(_ printerObj: Epos2Printer!, code: Int32, status: Epos2PrinterStatusInfo!, printJobId: String!) {
      
    let success = isPrintJobSuccess(by: code) // determine how a job is succeed
    self.completion?(success)
}
```

let's assume your class is called `Printer`, You could do this on you call site:

```swift
let printer = Printer()
printer.sendData(cmdData, portName: "port", portSettings: "settings", timeoutMilis: 1000, completion: { success in 
    if success {
        doSomeSuccessJob()
    }
})
// or you could use trailing closure
printer.sendData(cmdData, portName: "port", portSettings: "settings", timeoutMilis: 1000) { success in 
    if success {
        doSomeSuccessJob()
    }
}
```

refs: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Comment: Didn't know you can use closures this way., this answers it, Thanks!