# Activity indicator not showing in pagination for tableview in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, pagination, uiscrollview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using pagination for tableview, for that I have created spinner for tableview footer and calling that in `scrollViewDidEndDragging` but the spinner is not showing.. while pagination

**code**: with this code pagination is working but `createSpinnerFooter` is calling but not showing, why? where am i wrong. please guide me

```
 var currentPageNumberVM: Int = 1
 private func createSpinnerFooter() -> UIView {
    
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 100))
    
    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    spinner.center = footerView.center
    footerView.addSubview(spinner)
    spinner.startAnimating()
    return footerView
   }

   //and calling here
   func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

     //Bottom Refresh
     if scrollView == resultTableView{

        if (((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) >= scrollView.contentSize.height))
        //if scrollView.contentOffset.y > (resultTableView.contentSize.height-100-scrollView.frame.size.height)
        {
            resultTableView.tableFooterView = createSpinnerFooter()
            print("refresh called")
            self.refresh()
        }
    }
    }

   @objc func refresh() {
    if currentPageNumberVM <= searchData?.result?.jobs?.last_page ?? 1 {
        jobSearchResultServiceCall()//service call
        
    } else {
        self.view.makeToast("No more data to show")
    resultTableView.tableFooterView = nil

    }
   }
```

**Edit**: if i move `resultTableView.tableFooterView = nil` to else then issue is `createSpinnerFooter` is showing but once its load then cells not reloading i mean pagination is not working until i scroll again, why? where is the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's because of `resultTableView.tableFooterView = nil` in your `refresh()` function that causes the spinner to be removed as soon as it was added.

Here is how

1. First you add the spinner in `scrollViewDidEndDragging` with this line of code `resultTableView.tableFooterView = createSpinnerFooter()`
2. Then you call `self.refresh()` immediately which I believe calls an API in the background
3. However, in `refresh` you are also `nil` the footer view before the API call has completed `resultTableView.tableFooterView = nil`

All this happens so fast that you don't see the spinner being added and removed.

This line `resultTableView.tableFooterView = nil` should go in your `else` case and it should go in your API completion handler after the API has returned with a response or error

**Update**

You need to move `resultTableView.tableFooterView = nil` to two places.

One is in else block - OK, you have done this.

Another one is in the completion handler of your API call. It seems like your API call does not handle completion so I recommend you have a look at [resource 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401439/how-could-i-create-a-function-with-a-completion-handler-in-swift) and [resource 2](https://grokswift.com/completion-handlers-in-swift/) to understand how to set up a completion handler for your API call.

Completion handler will let you know when you api call has completed and this is the second place you need to make the spinner to nil.

You need to change your `jobSearchResultServiceCall()` to have a completion handler using the links above.

Once this is done, you will have code that looks like this

```
@objc func refresh() {

    if currentPageNumberVM <= searchData?.result?.jobs?.last_page ?? 1 {

        jobSearchResultServiceCall { [weak self] _ in
            // your API call has finished and here is the second place
            // to remove the spinner
            self?.resultTableView.tableFooterView = nil
        })
        
    } else {
        self.view.makeToast("No more data to show")
        resultTableView.tableFooterView = nil
    }
}
```

Now your spinner gets dismissed if api call has completed or there are no more results to show

Comment: thank for the reply

Comment: if i move `resultTableView.tableFooterView = nil` to else then issue is `createSpinnerFooter` is showing but once its load then cells not reloading i mean pagination is not working until i scroll again, why? where is the issue.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You need to introduce completion handler to your code.