# How can I know the all the asynchronous tasks are completed?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

There are two asynchronous tasks, and I don't know which of the two will be the last to finish. I want to do additional work after all the asynchronous tasks are completed, so how do you know that all asynchronous tasks have been completed?

Comment: Maybe you can checkout out Operation Queues and DispatchGroup. Here is a nice example of DispatchGroup - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rJN_ECd1XM&ab_channel=LetsBuildThatApp

Comment: Those are antiquated now. [TaskGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskgroup) is the replacement.

Comment: Antiquated is a bit strong!  Superseded by the new Concurrency features, but still perfectly valid esp in a legacy code base. Even Apple hasn’t depreciated them yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use completion handler. It is a useful feature that allows us to handle asynchronous actions whilst keeping the method call and the resultant code close together.

[Example of fully downloading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401439/how-could-i-create-a-function-with-a-completion-handler-in-swift)